# vc dll automatically unregister itself

Tags: windows

We have 2 DLLs. Both dll's do basically the same.
One DLL (DLL_A) is in one directory for a web page to run.
The other DLL (DLL_B) is in another directory where another
web page will call it. Both web pages are isolated. There is no
contact from one myWebA.htm to myWebB.htm.
D:\mywebA\myWebA.htm
D:\mywebA\DLL_A.dll

D:\myWebB\myWebB.htm
D:\myWebB\DLL_B.DLL

The DLL_A was written several years ago.
Recently we created DLL_B to be used in myWebB.
Now we are noticing this problem.

IF user web page calls DLL_A.dll, it unregister DLL_B.dll.
And vice versa.

Both DLL's can be registered.
The DLL that gets called FIRST, will unregister the other DLL.

One thing I noticed, which ever DLL is running will have the same PID
on the server (windows 2003).

If I could register these with a different PID  would that solve the problem?
if so how?

Any other Suggestions?

TIA
Steve42

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I assume you are talking about COM DLLs here, not any other.
In that case, possibly both your DLLs are having the same GUID. In that case, it will create a problem since only one DLL can be registered at a time since GUIDs need to be unique machine wide.

If you have Visual Studio installed, there are many tools such as COM Viewer which will tell you the GUID of both the DLLs on drag and drop.

Comment: Yes they have the same GUID. **How do I change it?** <br/ In the file OAIDL.H it has MIDL_INTERFACE("00020405-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")

Comment: @Steve42 - In that case, you have two options: [1] Either get the source-code and recompile either DLL_A or DLL_B (and remembering to change the GUID before recompiling). [2] Another way is to unregister both DLLs and just put them in their web application directories where they are needed. This way both DLLs won't have any visibility to each other and they will work on the same machine though they have the same GUID.

Comment: I want to change with a compile code in this DLL. I tried changing it in OAIDL.H. It did not work. I have tried changing it in other areas but it defaults back to the "00020405..." **Where do I change the GUID?**

Comment: Did you try the second method? It is easier. To unregister a dll, you simply run "regsvr32 C:\MY_PATH.DLL -u". Find and unregister all exising copies of DLL_A & DLL_B. Then before running your web-app, make sure that the needed DLL exists in the same path.

Comment: I tried 2nd method. It did not work. The web page has to create an object. Therefore with the DLL being unregister, I get error. **What do I need to do in changing the GUID of the DLL?**

Comment: You won't get the error if you put the DLL in the same folder as your .ASPX page which is doing Server.CreateObject.

Comment: It was in the same folder. I'm using .asp

Comment: Can't you try this? Insted of keeping DLL_A & DLL_B in separate directories can't you copy only one of them to a single location (such as C:\DLL_BLAH) and register it there? (But unregister from all other locations if you try this solution).

Comment: I think I got a workaround. I converted a DLL into Visual basic DLL. The other DLL is in visual C++. They still have the same PID, but I can run both DLL and it appears to work...